# Boost Spirit Qi Symbols default value and NULL value

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-qi

Boost Spirit qi::symbols implements a map of key-value pairs: give a key of a string, it can return a certain value. My questions are:

1) For a blank string, is it possible to return a default value? (Q1 in code)

2) For a string that is other than a blank string or the keys listed in the map of key-value pairs, is it possible to return a value indicating the key is invalid? (Q2 in code)

** The following code is based on the BOOST SPIRIT document.
** Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/support_utree.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/assert.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

template <typename P, typename T>
void test_parser_attr(
    char const* input, P const& p, T& attr, bool full_match = true)
{
    using boost::spirit::qi::parse;

    char const* f(input);
    char const* l(f + strlen(f));
    if (parse(f, l, p, attr) && (!full_match || (f == l)))
        std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "fail" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    using boost::spirit::qi::symbols;

    symbols<char, int> sym;
    sym.add
        ("Apple", 1)
        ("Banana", 2)
        ("Orange", 3)
    ;

    int i;
    test_parser_attr("Banana", sym, i);
    std::cout << i << std::endl;      // 2


    test_parser_attr("", sym, i);     // Q1: key is "",
    std::cout << i << std::endl;      // would like it to be 1 as default

    test_parser_attr("XXXX", sym, i); // Q2: key is other than "Apple"/"Banana"/"Orange",
    std::cout << i << std::endl;      // would like it to be 4

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't accomplish what you want using just a `qi::symbols`. It should be possible to create a Spirit terminal/directive that achieves the desired result but doing so would be really complex and require knowledge of the inner workings of `qi::symbols` and related classes, so I don't think it's a worthwhile approach. Luckily there is a really simple alternative using [`qi::attr(val)`](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/auxiliary/attr.html), a parser that doesn't consume any input, exposes `val` as its attribute and always succeeds.

Let's see all three cases:

- if the string is in the symbol table return its associated value `->`just use `sym`
- if the string is empty return 1 `->` just use `attr(1)`
- if the string is not in the symbol table return 4 `->` here you need to use `attr(4)` but that isn't enough since you also need to consume the string. If we assume the string is composed of only letters `omit[+alpha]` could work (`omit` discards the text, and `+` makes sure that there is at least one letter).

You need to put these three parsers in an [alternative parser](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/alternative.html) keeping in mind that the parser actually used in each case will be the first one to succeed:

```
sym | omit[+alpha] >> attr(4) | attr(1)
```

Possible problems:

- If your not-in-symbol-table string can be more complex you'll need to change `+alpha` appropriately.
- If you are using a skipper you'll probably need to use `omit[`**`lexeme`**`[+alpha]]` to stop the greedy `+`.

Full Sample [(Running on WandBox)](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/3cxOmjcZvUQqrio2)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>


template <typename P, typename T>
void test_parser_attr(
    char const* input, P const& p, T& attr, bool full_match = true)
{
    using boost::spirit::qi::parse;

    char const* f(input);
    char const* l(f + strlen(f));
    if (parse(f, l, p, attr) && (!full_match || (f == l)))
        std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "fail" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    using boost::spirit::qi::symbols;

    symbols<char, int> sym;
    sym.add
        ("Apple", 1)
        ("Banana", 2)
        ("Orange", 3)
    ;

    using boost::spirit::qi::attr; 
    using boost::spirit::qi::alpha;
    using boost::spirit::qi::omit;
    using boost::spirit::qi::lexeme;

    //if the text is in the symbol table return the associated value
    //else if the text is formed by letters (you could change this using for example `alnum`) and contains at least one, discard the text and return 4
    //else return 1
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<char const*,int()> symbols_with_defaults = sym | omit[+alpha] >> attr (4) | attr(1);


    int i;
    test_parser_attr("Banana", symbols_with_defaults, i);
    std::cout << i << std::endl;      // 2

    test_parser_attr("", symbols_with_defaults, i);     // Q1: key is "",
    std::cout << i << std::endl;      // would like it to be 1 as default

    test_parser_attr("XXXX", symbols_with_defaults, i); // Q2: key is other than "Apple"/"Banana"/"Orange",
    std::cout << i << std::endl;      // would like it to be 4

    std::vector<int> values;
    test_parser_attr("<Banana>,<>,<xxxx>", ('<' >> symbols_with_defaults >> '>')%',', values);
    for(int val : values)
        std::cout << val << " ";  // should be '2 1 4'
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Perfect solution, detailed explanation, quick response. Thank you very much.